# I'm using the PHPMailer to my website contact page , but I faced a problem , when the message is received both sender and receiver gmail are the same?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using the PHPMailer to my website contact page , but I faced a problem , when the message is received both sender and receiver gmail are the same?

```
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $name = filter_var( $_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['mail'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $body = filter_var($_POST['body'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';


        //SMTP Settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "@gmail.com"; //enter you email address
        $mail->Password = ''; //enter you email password
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

        //Email Settings
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
        $mail->addAddress("ennokhba22@gmail.com"); //enter you email address
        $mail->Subject = ($subject);
        $mail->From= $email; 
        $mail->Body = $body;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending via Gmail's SMTP servers, they ignore any `From` headers to prevent abuse. Your `From` will always be that of the Gmail account you're sending via.

You'll need a different email service provider if you want to send custom `From` headers, but note that this is likely to wind your emails up in spam unless you've got the rights (via SPF etc.) to send email on behalf of that custom address. You might consider a `Reply-To` header instead.

Comment: This is true. You can preconfigure aliases in gmail to send from other account names, but you can't use that to send from arbitrary addresses as you're trying to do. See [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) for guidance on the right way to build a contact form.